# How to investigate a proxy returning 400

Tags: java, http, ssl, http-headers, http-proxy

I have this java code:

```java
    u = new URL(url);
    c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    c.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    c.setReadTimeout(15000);
    c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
    if (url.startsWith("https://")) {
      ((javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection) c).setHostnameVerifier(SSLCertTruster.DO_NOT_VERIFY);
      }
```

I am accessing the URL https://hl7.org/fhir/us/core/package-list.json. On all but a few computers, this works fine. But on some computers (one windows, one mac), this code fails and the URL can't be accessed. In this case, the result of the HTTP call is HTTP 400 Bad Request with this body:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I assume this is a proxy... but I can't debug since it's not happening for me. I'm not sure what to look for?

Comment: On the computers that can't access that URL by java code, a browser can access it no problems.

Comment: maybe. I could ask for the logs... but the request is probably not making it to the server? I'll check

Comment: You're probably right actually.

Comment: There might be a firewall/proxy in use inside the non-working environment. Browsers and Java don't share the configuration regarding proxies, so the browser might know of the proxy to use while your Java application does not - and runs into errors which might not even originate from the requested web site. Ask about the required network setup regarding proxies.

Comment: The users do not set a proxy. So whatever proxy it is, it's transparent to the end users